# Box not automatically converted to reference

Tags: rust

I am storing a `Box` in a `HashMap`. I would like to retrieve those values and convert them into references to the boxed type. My code looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait A {}

trait B {
    fn get(&self, key: &'static str) -> Option<&A>;
}

struct C {
    map: HashMap<&'static str, Box<A>>,
}

impl B for C {
    fn get(&self, key: &'static str) -> Option<&A> {
        return self.map.get(key)
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
expected trait A, found struct `std::boxed::Box`
```

What is the proper way to convert `Option<&Box<&A>>` to `Option<&A>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dereference the box and create a reference to it:

```
impl B for C {
    fn get(&self, key: &'static str) -> Option<&A> {
        return self.map.get(key).map(|value| &**value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. Does that have any performance costs associated with it?

Comment: Also, is this safe? What happens if the instance of `C` is deallocated? It owns the `Box`, so the reference will no longer be valid, right?

Comment: Yes, this is safe thanks to the Rust borrow checker. Please read about [lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) to understand how it works.

Comment: @Max The `Box` is still owned by the HashMap. The reason it needs to be dereferenced twice is: once to access the Box from the Box reference returned from `get` and once to get the data _inside_ the `Box`. Then a reference to the inner data is returned. This is fine as long as the Box (which owns the data) lives longer than the reference. As antoyo says, this is enforced by lifetimes: The inferred lifetimes are actually: `fn get<'a>(&'a self, key: &'static str) -> Option<&'a A>`, which means that the returned reference cannot outlive `self`, which owns the HashMap, which owns the data.